# How does Agent Smith break free of Matrix's code and how is he not affected by the time manipulation of The Analyst?

Tags: the-matrix, agent-smith

In *The Matrix Resurrections*, Agent Smith breaks free of Matrix's code but it is not explicitly explained how he does it.

*[Matrix.fandom.com](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Agent_Smith#A_New_Form)* explains his connection to Neo but it still doesn't answer the question:

> As revealed in The Matrix Resurrections, as Neo was resurrected by the Analyst, Smith didn't remain deleted due to their connection with each other. Taking on a new outer shell, Smith became the amnesiac Neo's buisness partner, forgetting his own past in the process. When Neo began to remember, so did Smith, who enjoyed the freedom that the new Matrix gave him.

I've also searched through many articles that try to explain *The Matrix Resurrections* but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer.
*[Gamesradar](https://www.gamesradar.com/matrix-resurrections-ending-explained-neo-trinity-morpheus/)* provides some relevant information regarding the protagonists encountering with Agent Smith:

> Bugs and Morpheus help Neo escape and promise to help him save Trinity, who is also being kept alive by the machines. They log back into the Matrix and come across Groff’s Smith, who has completely broken free of the Matrix’s code. In this version of the Matrix, however, all rogue programs are removed when they are found by the machines, and Smith sees Neo’s presence as a threat to all unregulated programs. 
> ... 
>  Just as Neo and Trinity are about to escape, the Analyst hits pause once again and decides to shoot Trinity and rebuild the Matrix. However, a deus ex machina: the rogue Agent Smith, now fully out of the Matrix’s control, saves the day. He would rath be a free agent than let the Analyst’s Matrix continue as it is. He puts on some colored shades.

How does Agent Smith break free of Matrix's code?

Related questions/details (that can help providing an answer to the questions):

- How is Agent Smith not affected by the time manipulation of The Analyst? I thought he has some source code like Neo and they are somehow connected. However, Neo *is* affected by the time manipulation of The Analyst throughout the story. Did Agent Smith break free of Matrix's code before Neo? If yes, how? Did Neo break free of Matrix's code after connecting with Trinity then? The Analyst can't do anything to Neo and Trinity at the end of the story.

Comment: FYI I removed the unnecessary/overly specific tag.